# Regex not working properly, returns null when it shouldnt

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are a million regex questions out there, and I assure you I have read a million -1 of those! This is just one of those things that are not for me. I am trying to extract the price number (decimal or not) and the name of the item (everything between the price number and < br/>)

Input:

```
var content = "$22 M Uniform <br/>"
```

or something like this

```
var content = "$39 Day / Evening Class Tuition  <br/>"
```

or

```
var content = "$12.8 Weekend Class Payment <br/>"
```

my code :

```
   var itemprice = content.match(/(\d+)(d*(\.\d{1,2}))/);
   var itemname = content.match(/(\s)(.*?)</);
```

My Issue:

My `itemname` works as it should and returns properly however my number seeker seems to not work in the browser when I debug it `itemprice` is set to null. This is weird because when I try that code here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_i it works just fine, extracting the number.

For the website my code looks like:

```
 var str = "$39.56 Day / Evening Class Tuition  <br>";
 var patt1 =/(\d+)(d*(\.\d{1,2}))/;
 var matches = str.match(patt1)
 alert(matches[0]);
```

Comment: Probably the `d*`. That means *zero or more "d" characters*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple decimal regex with optional points is

```
/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/JXdbg/2/

For dollar-sign currency detection, I would prefix this with the `$`

```
/\$\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/
```

Comment: Ok I kept messing with it and it just worked, it was the way I phrased the code, not the regex, strange!.. BUT THANKS!